# In X11, how to detect if a window has opened or closed

Tags: x11, desktop

I am trying to write a simple panel to manage windows using X11. Is there a way to detect if a new window has open or closed in the DE? All i have found is information on events for a window that you have explicitly created, but nothing on detecting those events outside of that.

Comment: It's the job of the window manager (WM) to handle windows and their lifecycle (open/closed/iconified etc.). Which WM are you running? Are you trying to use your panel to replace a WM? Have you considered interacting with your WM directly to make it do what you want?